# Update Values in table by calling an SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

HI,

I have a table (lets call it `tblInsuranceInfo`) in which a single column needs to be updated by calling a stored proc (lets call it `ReturnscalculatedAge`). The update of the table will happen in the stored proc.

The `ReturnscalculatedAge` SP expects many parameters, some `tblInsuranceInfo` columns.

`ReturnscalculatedAge` SP also returns many values. But we need to set one of the values returned to the Column1 of `tblInsuranceInfo`.

How do I do this for each record in `tblInsuranceInfo` where `Column2 = 'something'`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your SP return the "many values" as a result set (from a `SELECT ....` statement), or as `OUTPUT` parameters for the stored proc??

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand: first you say, *the update of the table will happen in the stored proc* - yet, a couple lines later, you seem to want to call the stored proc and retrieve output values and **then** update the table.... didn't you just say the update happens **in** the stored proc?? What now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a way to call a SP in a set based way so here is a RBAR solution for you.
Assuming that your SP returns the value for Column2 as an out parameter and that you have an ID integer column as PK in tblInsuranceInfo.

```
declare @id int
declare @Col1 int

select @id = min(ID)
from tblInsuranceInfo
where Column2 = 'Something'

while @id is not null
begin
  --exec SP here get return value in @Col1

  update tblInsuranceInfo
  set Column1 = @Col1
  where ID = @id 

  select @id = min(ID)
  from tblInsuranceInfo
  where Column2 = 'Something' and
        ID > @id
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe RBAR is the only way here. I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple update to the tblInsuranceInfo inside the sp, before you return the values from it:

```
UPDATE tblInsuranceInfo
SET Column1 = @ParameterName
WHERE Column2 = @SomeOtherParameterName
```

Then, before the end of the stored proc do something like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM tblInsuranceInfo
WHERE Column2 = @SomeOtherParameterName
```

Comment: the trouble is that the value for Column1 comes from the SP ReturnscalculatedAge. SP ReturnscalculatedAge expects parameters from tblInsuranceInfo , say column3 and column4

Comment: Tough to say without seeing the stored proc, spReturnsCalculatedAge.  Are you updating multiple values at once, or a single value?  If multiple values, it might be best to put it inside the stored proc.  What are the parameters to sp?

Comment: As mentioned, the spReturnsCalculatedAge takes some of the row values as parameters, its a generic SP developed by other dept, so it returns many values, we need to use one of them and set it back in the row.